# Use OCamlFormat as a library

Tags: ocaml, metaprogramming

I would like to use `ocamlformat` as a library to automatically format some OCaml code I generate. There does not seem to be a simple function `format : string -> string`, but maybe there is a way to build it from existing components?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? How do you generate your code? If you generate it with the proper formatting you should need to format it afterwards. If you don't, usually you can invoke `dune build @fmt --auto-promote` to format it according with OCamlformat

Comment: you shouldn't* need to format it afterwards

Comment: I generate it by printing it based on a custom AST. By proper formatting do you mean ensuring by myself that everything that comes out of this printf is compatible with ocamlformat's standards? That sounds long and tedious.
Also, the code is not generated once and for all, it will be generated regularly on new ASTs.

Comment: And how would you want to invoke OCamlformat inside OCaml?

Comment: Why not do a Custom AST -> OCaml AST translation instead? `compiler-libs` has a `Printast` module that you can then use to print it, which isn't great, but probably better than a homebrew solution.

Comment: I will need to take a look at that, but I already have a substantial development with a homebrew solution, and rewriting it would be too complicated for now.